# AngularJS v1.3.13: Data change in the controller isn't reflected in the view

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm running into a weird problem, after I bind an object in the controller to the $scope, any further changes to the object are not reflected in the view.

here is my code:

View:

```
<input id="search-input" type="text" ng-model="model.keywords" />
<span class="tool" ng-click="methods.clearInput()"></span>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('someController', function($scope) {
   var model = {
      keywords: ''
   };
   var methods = {
      clearInput: function() {
         model.keywords = '';
      }
   };
   $scope.model = model;
   $scope.methods = methods;
}
```

The input is cleared only once on the first click, after that - clicking the clear  element does nothing. I tried wrapping the change with $scope.$apply() like so:

```
clearInput: function() {
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      model.keywords = '';
   });
}
```

But the change is still not reflected in the view. I know i can make the change to the $scope's variable, but then why use the two-way binding to begin with?

My question is: what's the proper way to bind the controller's variables to the scope & have the changes made in the controller reflect in the view?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I have no trouble running your code. What are you changing in the controller that is not reflected in the view? Using your code, whenever I enter text, and click the span element/run `clearInput()` it clears the next (not just on the first time only).

Comment: You're right. the problem was a CSS selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a CSS selector. try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        input:not(:focus) + span {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input" type="text" />
<span id="span">woop</span>

<script>
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var span = document.getElementById("span");

    span.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("was clicked!");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess its because the browser renders the CSS faster than the JavaScript code is invoked :)